# how to differentiate media screen for ipad and ipad pro in css

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

so, I want to make a responsive loader (image). that the position always in the middle of the screen and the width always follow the size of the screen. So, I used @media only screen for do that, and now I have a problem to differentiate the size for ipad and ipad pro.

this is the code:

```css
  /*ipad portrait*/
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
     .sp-conload img{
      width: 100%;
         height: auto;
      margin-top: -330px;
     }
    }
    
    /*ipad landscape*/
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
     .sp-conload img {
        width: 65%;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: -290px;
     }
    }
    
    /*ipad pro portrait*/
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) and (max-device-width : 1366px) and (orientation : portrait) { 
     .sp-conload img{
      width: 100%;
         height: auto;
      margin-top: -460px;
     }
    }
    
    /*ipad pro landscape*/
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 1024px) and (max-device-width : 1366px) and (orientation : landscape) { 
     .sp-conload img{
      width: 70%;
         height: auto;
      margin-top: -440px;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="sp-conload">
        <div class="sp-loader" >  
                        <h2 id="anim9" class="frame-9"><span><img src="../img/loader/9.png"></span></h2>
                        <h2 id="anim8" class="frame-8"><span><img src="../img/loader/8.png"></span></h2>
                        <h2 id="anim7" class="frame-7"><span><img src="../img/loader/7.png"></span></h2>
                        <h2 id="anim6"class="frame-6"><span><img src="../img/loader/6.png"></span></h2>
                        <h2 id="anim5" class="frame-5"><span><img src="../img/loader/5.png"></span></h2>
                        <h2 id="anim4" class="frame-4"><span><img src="../img/loader/4.png"></span></h2>
                        <h3 id="anim10" class="frame-10"><span><img src="../img/loader/10.png"></span></h3>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the problem is, when I open with ipad it will use the ipad pro, but if I used `!important` in ipad size, when I open with ipad pro it will use the ipad size, because they have `max-device-width : 1024px` for ipad, and `min-device-width : 1024px` for ipad pro, and I think it clashed. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is the newer way to put an image in the center of the screen. However, some of the styles here are not supported by the older browsers. The good thing though is that you don't need all of those @media styles :)

```
.sp-conload img{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: when I used landscape, the ratio of the image is not same as portrait :(